# Link open in new tab and focus on previous tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

How to make the focus remains on the same tab while a link is opening in new tab in the background though jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
   <p>Click the button to open a new window, and assure that the new window GETS focus (send the new window to the front).</p>
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=200,height=100");
        myWindow.document.write("<p>A new window!</p>");
        myWindow.focus();
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it is opening in a new window..

Comment: Rose : What u exactly want to achieve?

Comment: @Swetha:I want a tab to be opened in background on click of a link not a new window..